# bash script variable passing to find

Tags: bash, variables, find

I have a simple bash script where I generate some temporary files using split, do some processing and then try to track down all the files at the end and merge them

```
rand_int=$RANDOM
split -d -l $n_lines_split $1 $rand_int   #works fine

for f in $(find . -amin -200 -regex '.*$rand_int.*' ); do 
    (some processing here) ; 
done
```

My problem is that in the find command $rand_int is interpreted literally,  whereas I want to use the variable's value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the shell, single-quotes (`'`) cause what's inside to be interpreted literally. What you want to do is use double-quotes (`"`) around the expression with `$rand_int`.

So for the `find` expression:

```
find . -amin -200 -regex ".*$rand_int.*"
```

Comment: beautiful! 
Funny,  I used to use Perl (same convention), and that hadn't even occurred to me

Answer (score 2):

use " " instead of ''

```
for f in $(find . -amin -200 -regex ".*$rand_int.*" ); do
```